# Fastest way to tile a drawing with pixi.js?

Tags: pixi.js

I have a computationally heavy drawing that is rendered by a pixi.js render.
I then create sprites from the renderer view in order to tile the drawing horizontally and I render the sprites on the on-screen canvas (using webgl as auto-detected)
However, I find the whole operation to be still slow. Can you tell how performances could be improved? I'm not sure if [RenderTexture](http://pixijs.github.io/docs/PIXI.RenderTexture.html) could be used instead, and if it would make a significant gain.
Thanks for your help, this is a code extract of my script:

```
 var canvasRenderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(w, h, {
   view :        $('#canvas')[0],    
   clearBeforeRender :     false  
 });

 var canvasGraphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
 var canvasStage = new PIXI.Container(); 
 canvasStage.addChild(canvasGraphics);
 canvasGraphics.beginFill();

   var renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width, height);
   var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
   var stage = new PIXI.Container();
   stage.addChild(graphics);
   graphics.beginFill();

   // Whole lotta rects
   for (var i in rects) {         
     graphics.drawRect(
       rects[i].left, rects[i].top, rects[i].width, rects[i].height
     );
   }
   graphics.endFill();
   renderer.render(stage);

   for (var j = 0; j <= loops; j++) {
     var sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(renderer.view);
       sprite.x = j * width;
       canvasStage.addChild(sprite);
     }
   }

 canvasGraphics.endFill();
 canvasRenderer.render(canvasStage);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PIXI has a `TilingSprite` for exactly this purpose.

If you're drawing graphics, you should use a `RenderTexture`, and then put that into a `TilingSprite`.

```js
    var renderer = new PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(width, height);
    var stage = new PIXI.Container();

    //Draw your Graphics
    var graphics = new PIXI.Graphics();
    graphics.beginFill();
    for (var i in rects) {         
        graphics.drawRect(
            rects[i].left, rects[i].top, rects[i].width, rects[i].height
        );
    }
    graphics.endFill();

    //Create a RenderTexture to hold the Graphics.
    //I don't know the size of your Graphics, so I'm making it up as 50 x 50
    var texture = new PIXI.RenderTexture(new PIXI.BaseRenderTexture(50, 50));
    
    //Render the Graphics into the Texture
    renderer.render(graphics, texture);

    //Create a TilingSprite from the Texture
    var tilesprite = new PIXI.extras.TilingSprite(texture, renderer.width, renderer.height);
    stage.addChild(tilesprite);

    renderer.render(stage);
```